# templateUrl vs template in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, directive

I think for routing, `templateUrl` should always be used over `template`. But for a directive, when should `templateUrl` be used instead of `template`? I see some people use chunks of HTML in string format as `template`, whereas others link all their directives to a `templateUrl`, even if the template is really simple and small.

So, what is the best practice for deciding which one to use? I am personally more in favour of using `templateUrl` regardless of the template's complexity, just because I hate putting HTML in strings, but I would love to learn about reasons beyond just subjective emotions.

Comment: This is all down to opinion and your workflow. I personally never use `template` because as part of my build process I embed all my templates into `$templateCache` with grunt-angular-templates

Comment: Ah I feel so silly now. The answer is stated in the documentation: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive "Best Practice: Unless your template is very small, it's typically better to break it apart into its own HTML file and load it with the templateUrl option."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cones down to preference, really. In general I agree with you, and more complex markup always makes more sense in a separate template due to ease of editing.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post about this: http://www.smarpshare.com/angular-template-vs-templateurl-the-move-toward-true-modular-development/ . In a nutshell, I find it is better to use dependency management system and `template` to organize your Angular project; it will help you to migrate to Angular 2 too!

Comment: Link is now dead

Answer (score 0):

If you using lots of template in your project like SPA application with huge html rendered going on inside each template and of-course if you want to manage your application well for future then keep it separate.